# Normaliztion of a random variable.

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have a column of data(random variable)
 and I need to transform that data in to normal random variable how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Under some conditions you could use the central limit theorem. It states that if $(X_{i})_{i \geq 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables which satisfy $\mathbb{E}[X_{1}^{2}] < +\infty$, then

$$ \frac{S_{n} - \mathbb{E}[S_{n}]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[S_{n}]}} \, \mathop{\longrightarrow} \limits^{\mathcal{L}}_{n \to +\infty} \, \mathcal{N}(0,1) $$

with $\displaystyle S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k}$. So, if each coordinate of you vector is a random variable, if all these variables are independent and have the same distribution, if the length of your vector is large, you could consider that

$$ \frac{S_{n}-\mathbb{E}[S_{n}]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}[S_{n}]}}$$

follows a gaussian distribution.

Comment: how about defining a new variable $ z= x - \bar{x} $